# Navbar text size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar in Bootstrap. My grid is set to "md", so when I reduce my sreen, there is a moment where the navbar items disappear and are put in a single dropdown button. I.e., it collapses properly. The only remaining items in my navbar are the brand and the dropdown button.

But when I increase the text size, such as

```
.navbar {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

there is an intermediate step where the navbar items go under the logo (between 768px and 991px) and I don't want this. How can avoid that and make the logo and the items be on the same line until there is a lack of place (and the menu items get available in a dropdown menu button) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Solved with media queries :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

       .navbar-collapse.collapse  {
           display: none!important;
       }
       .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
            display: block !important;
        }
        .navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
            display:block !important;
        }
        .navbar-header {
            float:none;
        }
    }
```